# Active Directory Web SSO, providing metadata for trust relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, metadata

My web application is hosted over www.mydomain.com i have used formsauthentication. Which is already running and over 10000 clients are there.

Now another client having its 1000 employees needs access to our application and data, but they dont want to remember or enter password while login, so we came up with the solution for web SSO using active directory services. I know that using windows identity we can get the logged in username, and using that i can logged in that user to web application.

But i got an email to provide metadata to the client for active directory trust relationship. So what is the steps to provide metadata? May i have to provide my dll for this metadata. I am very much confused.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory Federation Services 2?

Comment: Yes my client using ADFS 2.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS2 publishes the metadata at

```
https://[adfs.domain]/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
```

If you are using ADFS at your side, the metadata is available under the same convention. If you have a custom STS, you somehow have to provide the metadata. I've blogged on this once

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/09/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web_12.html